# Javascript Functions: function Footer() vs. const Footer = () =>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

What is the difference between these two functions? They both seem to produce the same output.

Pros and cons?
Or are they exactly the same?

```
const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <Footer>This is the footer</Footer>
    )
}
```

and

```
function Footer() {
    return (
        <Footer>This is the footer</Footer>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one will:

- be [`hoisted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)
- create it's own context

First one won't do either.